# Filming location for prison in The Prestige (2006) and Papillon (2017)

Tags: film-location

I'm looking for two filming locations that I suspect might be the shot at the same location:

- the prison from [The Prestige (2006)](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0482571/) where Borden is locked up
  [image: Prison in The Prestige]
- the first prison location in [Papillon (2017)](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt5093026/) where the Papillon character is locked up before he is shipped to French Guiana
  [image: Prison in Papillon]

I can see that the first one has a brick wall and the second on a plastered wall, but when watching the film I had a feeling the location as a whole looked very similar.

I reviewed the filming locations as listed on IMDb, and it appears that Papillon was shot mainly in Europe and The Prestige in the USA, but I don't know if that listing is complete.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I doubt they're the same. I found two other sources for locations info on both movies & they don't really even share a continent.
[The Prestige Locations](https://www.latlong.net/location/the-prestige-locations-282) claims it's entirely US-based.
[Papillon remake starring Charlie Hunnam wraps filming in Malta](https://www.thelocationguide.com/2016/12/papillon-remake-starring-charlie-hunnam-wraps-filming-in-malta/) mentions several, from Malta to Montenegro, but nothing US.

One thing you will never be able to tell from either of those shots - nor even sometimes if you see things in long-shot [I can't remember how wide we ever see these two locations in the movies] - is if they're even *real* places or movie sets, indoors or out.

You can literally rent a prison if you need one - here are some from the UK on [UKFilmLocation.com](https://ukfilmlocation.com/locations?search%5B0%5D=Prison%20Cell) - but sometimes it's easier/cheaper to build one. You'd be amazed at how big a set can be sometimes… especially if they fill the distance with CGI.

This is one on a backlot at Warner Leavesden. I've been on it [though they've changed it a lot since for another movie the basic structure is still the same]
Spot the join between real & CGI. I know where it is & I still can't see it.

[image]

This entire movie was shot indoors on sound stages and you *still* can't tell

[image]

Just for fun - everything below the red line is real [ including the cars and people etc], everything above is CGI.

[image]

<sup>I might be one floor out, left or right. Even knowing, it's still impossible to tell for sure</sup>